# JavaScript - How to loop through array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, keycloak

I have been working on keycloak admin rest api method and I got most of the method working. I am able to create users and create roles using excel sheet read in nodejs and that works well. I am able to list all user and list all roles created. Now what i want to do is check if the role exist in the excel file using comma separated and then assign that users only the roles method in the excel file

I will share my code

**function read user and role**

```
let userRoleTobCreated = ReadFromExcel('./uploads/employees-roles.xlsx');
function ReadFromExcel() {
    let userRoleTobCreated = []
    xlsxFile(filename).then((rows) => {
        rows.forEach(row => {
            let userObject = {
                username: row[0],
                lastName: row[1],
                firstName: row[2],
                email: row[3],
                roles: row[4].split(",")
            }
            userRoleTobCreated.push(userObject);
        });
    })
    return userRoleTobCreated;
}
```

**Output**

[image]

here I want to check the employee excel file and according the role in the column i want to assign to each user each role but it does not work it just assign four roles to first four users

[image]

**Function Call**

```
GetUser(userid, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
 userid = resp.data.map(userRoleTobCreated => userRoleTobCreated.id);

  GetRole(roleId, roleName, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
   roleId = resp.data.map(userRoleTobCreated => userRoleTobCreated.id);
   roleName = resp.data.map(userRoleTobCreated => userRoleTobCreated.name);

// Call Api to loop through each customer and assign each role to each customer
// this method just loops through the four role and assign it to the first four users only

      for (var i = 0; i < userid.length; i++) {
      AssignRole(userid[i], roleId[i], roleName[i], kc_clientUUID, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
                    })
                }
            })
        })
```

**output - the role for each user not the way the excel file is specified**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Keycloak response, besides the `user ID`, you will also need its `username`, why? Because with that `username` you can match the `username` retrieved from Excel.

```
GetUser(userid, kc_accessToken).then((resp) => {
 ...
 usernames = resp.data.map(userRoleTobCreated => userRoleTobCreated.username);
```

Now you have the user's `IDs` and `usernames`, which will be needed to create the roles on Keycloak and match the Excel content, respectively.

Then you must get the `username` from the array `usernames`, search on the `userRoleTobCreated` for that `username`, and get its `roles`. Then, you will add those roles to the user. For that, first you will have to use the `role name` extracted from Excel, and get its corresponding index on your `roleName` array. You will use that index to get the `role ID` from the array `roleId`. The code would be something like:

```
// For each userID retrieved from Keycloak
for (var i = 0; i < userid.length; i++) {
    roles = []
    // Find the username and get its roles
    for (var j = 0; j < userRoleTobCreated.length; j++)
        if(usernames[i] == userRoleTobCreated[j].username){
           roles = userRoleTobCreated[j].roles
           break;  
        }

    // add each one of the roles
    for(var r = 0; r < roles.length; r++){
       role_pos = roleName.indexOf(role[r])
       role_id = roleId[role_pos]
       AssignRole(userid[i], role_id, role[r], kc_clientUUID, kc_accessToken)...
    }
};
```

Now bear in mind that, I do not know about JavaScript, Node.js, and so on. So this pseudo-code might need some adaptions, probably in terms of better idioms and performance. Nevertheless, the *algorithm* is there.

I would also rename some of your variables `userid`, `roleId`, and `roleName` to `userIDs`, `roleIDs`, and `roleNames`, respectively. The original names make the code slightly hard to follow, and are also misleading.

Comment: That's so kind of you thank you so much once again. Cheers